# Preprocessing train test data

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I have `X numpy array` as my features and `y numpy array` as my target. I split both of it into train and test data. From many `QnA` i have read they only say to `preprocess` both train and test separately. I assume i only do it to my feature (X) train and test data and not the target (y). Do we also `preprocess` the target?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the preprocessing is applied to the **X** but you can process the target **Y** data using transformers like  [TransformedTargetRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html). You can read more about its usage and why its recommended. Sometimes, the nature of what you are predicting may work better with a transformed target.